# SSH server accepts key, but signing fails

Tags: ssh, gpg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

I have recently tried migrating from a standard ssh public key setup to managing my keys with GPG. Following [instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#SSH_agent) on my distribution's wiki, I set up ssh to use `gpg-agent` instead of the default `ssh-agent`. I am quite certain that went fine: even with my `~/.ssh` directory removed, `ssh-add -l` shows the one key I set up for it in gpg.

After that, I set the contents of my remote's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to exactly the output of local `ssh-add -L` and restarted the daemon.

Now trying to connect to my remote using `ssh -v <myremote>`, I get the following error:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: (none) RSA SHA256:<myfingerprint> agent
debug1: Server accepts key: (none) RSA SHA256:<myfingerprint> agent
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zoickx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zoickx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zoickx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zoickx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zoickx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
<myremote>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Clearly, server agrees that my public key is authorized, but, for a reason that's unclear to me, refuses to continue.

The common answers if googling "`sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed`" are to use `ssh-add` to add the missing private key or to change the permissions on keyfiles. Neither of these seem to be helpful in my case, using gpg-agent. My key does seem to be available to ssh, and there are no files to change permissions of.

A couple of things I am worried about:

- I do not get prompted for gpg's pinentry at any point
- The public key has the form `ssh-rsa <key> (none)`, ending with the strange "none" instead of the standard `user@host`.

Additional information about my setup:

- gpg 2.2.15
- libgcrypt 1.8.4
- Output of `gpgconf`:

```
gpg:OpenPGP:/usr/bin/gpg
gpg-agent:Private Keys:/usr/bin/gpg-agent
scdaemon:Smartcards:/usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon
gpgsm:S/MIME:/usr/bin/gpgsm
dirmngr:Network:/usr/bin/dirmngr
pinentry:Passphrase Entry:/usr/bin/pinentry
```

- gpg functions as expected for encryption/decryption, with pinentry working
- Not running Gnome or any other desktop environment - using dwm
- seahorse is installed

Comment: Which version of gpg ... `gpg --version` ... and is there a pinentry program listed in gpg config ... `gpgconf` ... and does gpg function as expected with encryption and decryption processes other than integration with ssh-agent ... lastly, are you running Gnome along with its password manager `seahorse`  or some other desktop?

Comment: @RubberStamp , edited my post with the answers

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not being prompted to enter your GPG passphrase, the problem *may be* that the running gpg-agent cannot access the display/terminal. I encountered the same symptoms on Mac OS 10.14 (Mojave) with GPG version 2.2.17.

I found a workaround in the man page for gpg-agent:

> Note:  in case the gpg-agent receives a signature request, the user
>   might need to be prompted for a passphrase, which is necessary for
>   decrypting the stored key.  Since the ssh-agent protocol does not
>   contain a mechanism for telling the agent  on  which display/terminal 
>   it  is  running,  gpg-agent's ssh-support will use the TTY or X
>   display where gpg-agent has been started.  To switch this display to
>   the current one, the following command may be used:
>
> ```
>      gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
> ```

While I have not found a permanent solution, this command works for me. It needs to be repeated after each restart.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I've been being stuck on the same issue.